# Which are the most common pitfalls with conditional (if) statements in C++?

Tags: c++

***Preface***

*This question is meant as a canonical collection of the most frequent (beginner) mistakes using conditional statements like `if() ... else` or similar.
Answers are meant to describe **unexpected behaviors at runtime**, syntactical flaws and misconceptions like*

> ```
> if(x) {}
> else (y) {}
> ```

*should not be addressed here.*

---

#### Addressed issues

- [**Misconceptions of conditional expressions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959877/8242698)
- [**Formatting and scoping errors**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959897/8242698)

Comment: A decent compiler will at least warn about any of the things you can think of. This is not a good question for Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I think I've read something like this on Code Complete 2 or somewhere...

Comment: @rubenvb Not very constructive in this context.

Comment: While the thought behind this canonical is very good, I don't think it's something that warrants a canonical dup at all. Novices fall into it by mistyping. Their problem is a typographical one. So it should be closed as one.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm doing that all the time already ;-). That was my motivation to come up with something more helpful I could point them to.

Comment: That's good. Problem is that if their post is closed as a duplicate of this instead of a "typo", it doesn't get automatically deleted by the system. So SO will start retaining these white noise questions en-masse.

Comment: @StoryTeller Badly received dupes as an outcome of _low research efforts_ will be well wiped out by the _roomba script_ already.

Comment: @user0042 - Yes. Except you've just increased their minimum retention from 9 days to 30, or even a whole year.

Comment: For me this should be closed as too broad/primarily opinion based. Not possible due to bounty though.

Answer (score 8):

### Misconceptions of conditional expressions

- > ```
  > if(x = 1) // ...
  > ```
  >
  > Equality comparisons are expressed using the `==`. `=` is an assignment, and the result is evaluated as a *cast* to `bool`. I.e. any value evaluated to `!= 0` results in `true`. As a prevention mechanism consider the below expressions:
- > ```
  >    if(1 = x)  // invalid assignment compilation error!
  >    if(1 == x) // valid equality comparison
  > ```
  >
  > A wrong use of an assignment operator can be avoided by always placing the constant on the left hand side of the expression. The compiler will flag any mistake triggering an invalid assignment error.
- > ```
  > if(answer == 'y' || 'Y')
  > ```
  >
  > <sub>Variations: `if(answer == 'y','Y')`</sub>
  >   Conditions must be tested with separate comparisons. The `||` operator binding doesn't do what's expected here. Use `if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')`instead.
- > ```
  > if (0 < x < 42)
  > ```
  >
  > Valid syntax in Python, with expected behaviour, that syntax is valid in C++, but parsed as `if ((0 < x) < 42)` so `false`/`true` converted to `0`/`1` and then tested against `< 42` -> always `true`.
  >   Condition must be tested with separate comparisons: `if (0 < x && x < 42)`

Answer (score 5):

### Formatting and scoping errors

- > ```
  > if(mycondition);
  > {
  >     // Why this code is always executed ???
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > There's a superfluous **`;`** after the `if()` statement.
- > ```
  > if(mycondition)
  >      statement1();
  >      statement2(); // Why this code is always executed ???
  > ```
  >
  > The code is equivalent to
  >
  > ```
  > if(mycondition) {
  >      statement1();
  > }
  > statement2();
  > ```
  >
  > `statement2();` is outside the scope of the conditional block. Add `{}` to group statements.
- > ```
  > if (mycondition)
  >      if (mycondition2)
  >          statement1();
  >  else
  >      statement2();
  > ```
  >
  > The code is equivalent to
  >
  > ```
  > if(mycondition) {
  >  if (mycondition2)
  >      statement1();
  >  else
  >      statement2();
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > `else` apply on previous `if`. Add `{}`:
  >
  > ```
  > if (mycondition) {
  >     if (mycondition2)
  >          statement1();
  > }
  > else
  >     statement2();
  > ```

---

The same applies for any wrongly placed `;` in loop statements like

- > ```
  >   for(int x = 0;x < 5;++x);
  >                        // ^
  >   {
  >        // statements executed only once
  >   }
  > ```

or

- > ```
  > while(x < 5);
  >          // ^
  > {
  >     // statements executed only once
  > }
  > ```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (north) {

} else if (south) {

} else if (west) {

} else if (east) {

}
```

potential missing else-clause for wrong direction.

Funny placement of {} because they add them, misplace them and then delete the wrong ones.

```
if (a) {
}
if (b) {
}
if (c) {
}
```

missing else as only one of them should be done even if more is true.