# Why is this C++ code not working (simple)

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have basically started learning C++. I have previously done coding on python 3.6, so I am somewhat unfamiliar to this structure. Sorry beforehand for asking such a simple question. The problem: Nothing is coming as output. Desired output: 4 sentences as seen in the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void mice(int);
void run(int);

int main()
{
    mice(2);
    run(2);
    return 0;
}
void mice(int n)
{
    while (n > 0);
    {
        cout << "Three blind mice";
        n --;
    }
}
void run(int n)
{
    while (n > 0);
    {
        cout << "See how they run";
        n --;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `;` after the while

Comment: Remove the ; after while.

Comment: `while (n > 0);` Is a loop with an empty body (due to semicolon at the end), and since `n` doesn't change - it is an infinite loop as well.

Comment: Please take the [tour] again, and focus on visiting the [ask] page.

Comment: My compiler gives a warning and points at the semicolon. If your do not, you might want to increase the warning level. Use `/W4` or `-pedantic` depending on what you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which are the most common pitfalls with conditional (if) statements in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959876/which-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-with-conditional-if-statements-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (n > 0);` causes endless loop. It should be `while (n > 0)`

relevant post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202734/putting-semicolons-after-while-and-if-statements-in-c

Answer (score 1):

on the lines with a while... line `while (n > 0);` the `;` completes the statement so it sits in the while loop, but `n` never changes.

If you remove the `;` then the loop body between the `{}` will execute.

e.g.

```
void mice(int n)
{
    while (n > 0)
    {
        cout << "Three blind mice";
        n --;
    }
}
```